# Автоподдомены для сайта в ispmanager

Tags: apache, веб-сервер, сервер, ispmanager

Есть сайт (site.com) файлы для сайта берутся с /www

Нужно автоподдомены (user1.site.com, user2.site.com) чтоб **все** работали с **одной** папки (напр. /users) не ***/www***

Google и Доки не помогли...

Есть возможность купить еще айпишник. Есть смысл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конфиг апача

```
ServerName site.comServerAlias user1.site.com user2.site.com
```